# Extracting data from HTTP header in C

Tags: c, networking, websocket, libpcap

I want to extract some data from an HTTP header using C to perform some checks. This is the code that I am using to extract the data. Here I am just trying to check whether the `Sec-WebSocket-Key` is 13 or not.

[image: Sample HTTP header]

I have used libpcap to read the pcap file as a command line argument.

```
    const u_char *payload;
    payload = packet+total_headers_size
    const u_char *token;
    token = strtok(payload, "\r\n\r\n");
    while (token)
    {
        printf("Current token: %s\n", token);
        const u_char *buff;
        sprintf(buff,"%s",token);
        /*if(strcmp(token,"HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols")==0)
        {
            printf("Protocol switched\n");   
        }*/
        if(strcmp(buff,"Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13")==0)
        {
            printf("Correct Version\n");
        }
        //printf("%d\n",sec);
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
```

The variable `payload` contains the HTTP header request and I have split the header based on `\r\n\r\n`, but I am not getting the desired output. `Total_headers_size` is the sum of the Ethernet header len, IP header len, and TCP header len.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The second argument to [`strtok`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) is not a substring to split on - it is a set of delimiting characters to look for. `"\r\n\r\n"` *is* `"\r\n"`, since duplicated characters are redundant. `"\r\n"` would produce the same tokens for `"hello\r\nworld"` and `"hello\n\r\r\r\nworld"`; the repeated delimiting characters would be skipped as `strok` scans for the start of the next token (resulting arrays: `"hello\0\nworld"` and `"hello\0\r\r\r\nworld"`, tokens for both: `"hello"`, `"world"`).

Comment: `const u_char *buff; sprintf(buff,"%s",token);` - `buff` is an uninitialized, indeterminate pointer value - effectively pointing to random memory. Trying to write a string to this memory is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). I see no reason *not* to use `token` directly. `token = strtok(NULL, "\n");` should again be `token = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");` or the carriage return will be present in subsequent tokens. +1 to Remy's point about the lack a of a null-terminating byte in the packet data.

Comment: For concrete answers, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can compile, and that reproduces the problem. To simplify: reconstruct a set of response headers as a string buffer within the source of your program, and operate on that.